# Updating long string through SQL Server Query Analyzer

Tags: sql-server, query-analyzer

I have a really long string of text that I would like to update a particular column in a table.  The update statement in sql query analyzer is on one long line currently.  Is there a way to break up the update statment into multiple lines for easier reading of the update statement?

Comment: breakup the update statement or the single string for one column update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query analyzer lets you put line breaks into literals:

```
insert into tbl (x) values ('hello
world')
```

But this inserts a CR as well. The other suggestion:

```
insert into tbl (x) values ('hello ' +
'world')
```

is standard procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is string concatenation?

You can do an update like this:

```
Update YourTable
Set Col1 = 'Start of some long string' + 
'End of the long string'
Where SomeColumn = SomeValue
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem having an UPDATE statement over multiple lines. Something like:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET col1 = 
  'New value for column 1'
 ,col2 = 
  'New value for column 2'
WHERE col3 = 7
```

...is just fine.